# Move rivers located in AK and HI to match plot_usmap

Tags: r, maps, r-sf

I made a lovely chloropleth using `plot_usmap` from the `usmap` package:

```r
plot_usmap(data = state_difference, values = "my_variable") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    scale_fill_stepsn(breaks = as.vector(quantile(state_difference$median_premium, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/5))), colors = heat.colors(5)) +
    labs(title = "Graph title")
```

Then someone said, "You know what?  We should put topographical features on this map."  So I found a good shapefile defining rivers:

```r
rivers <- st_read("sources/river_files")

## Match projection to that of 'plot_usmap' (ESRI:102003):
rivers2 <- sf::st_transform(rivers, "ESRI:102003")
```

And this is *so close*:

```r
plot_usmap(data = state_difference, values = "my_variable") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    scale_fill_stepsn(breaks = as.vector(quantile(state_difference$median_premium, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/5))), colors = heat.colors(5)) +
    labs(title="Graph title") +
    geom_sf(rivers2)
```

The problem is that `plot_usmap` puts Alaska and Hawaii south of the continental US, while the shapefile puts them in their actual locations.  So I need to move the rivers in Alaska and Hawaii south of the continental US to match `plot_usmap`.

The usual method (see [here](https://rud.is/b/2014/11/16/moving-the-earth-well-alaska-hawaii-with-r/)) involves having geoms labeled "Alaska" and "Hawaii" that can be transformed, but the shapefile just has the rivers.  I tried applying `shift_geometry` to `rivers2`, but the result was garbage.

Sample state data:

```
structure(list(state = c("HI", "WV", "MS", "AL", "LA", "NJ"), 
    value = c(10951.893, 11088.963, 58661.391, 32610.476, 543746.029, 
    105367.232)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Sample rivers data:

```
structure(list(NAMEEN = c("Kigalik River", "Maybe Creek", "Canning River", 
"Hulahula River", "Jago River"), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(-2899252.91587767, 
-2899312.64601041, -2903046.31714341, -2909538.23596611, -2911302.61092802, 
-2914750.27748601, -2918789.31605733, -2922075.39177455, -2924200.79458146, 
-2926396.01465823, -2929253.81477254, -2931621.18065852, -2933357.06098142, 
-2937854.95625042, -2938794.60865356, -2942085.2347789, -2943084.7635867, 
-2943154.3625061, -2944788.90979832, -2946543.19849677, -2948238.24538405, 
-2949678.70773815, -2955522.29616087, -2956126.13419868, -2958998.8998913, 
-2960102.11139554, -2961572.49799357, -2963256.36542367, -2964385.6207291, 
-2968334.16733643, -2970077.83291074, -2971493.12021008, -2973130.40390839, 
-2977842.69472845, -2980109.87122154, -2981192.73175109, -2982395.52402644, 
-2985001.06435783, -2987804.6996, -2990072.09038422, 4239476.95011435, 
4237821.92721547, 4237140.47059142, 4238882.29842369, 4239875.86641957, 
4242540.02891328, 4244900.97267643, 4247208.85389156, 4247048.23873586, 
4249769.38355097, 4252727.02820637, 4254621.48491297, 4255611.66104693, 
4259709.13053415, 4261319.54587873, 4263635.1126088, 4264566.25816588, 
4266268.42646858, 4267418.87482698, 4268425.14310217, 4270077.800334, 
4271567.06528524, 4278514.07466109, 4279414.13570809, 4282372.70376572, 
4283150.69760176, 4283957.52851983, 4284441.74348548, 4284534.82538005, 
4287074.78088274, 4291138.16264392, 4291432.37237433, 4292588.16580516, 
4296390.90840629, 4298450.61737576, 4299215.80365335, 4299837.67860639, 
4300729.39398182, 4301301.24570256, 4301496.30889971), dim = c(40L, 
2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-2856799.26426802, 
-2856311.3774156, -2855609.51715275, -2856077.3203322, -2857126.77877474, 
-2858948.24273194, -2872393.15940038, -2874313.77029371, -2875834.36391061, 
-2877276.34536589, -2878955.96798146, -2881164.65323986, -2881924.09427179, 
-2889003.39897877, -2892897.33899493, -2896405.57923701, -2897490.38244475, 
-2898383.6108713, -2899363.17790892, -2899322.5355603, -2898044.52526552, 
-2897820.96246425, -2899252.91587767, 4210892.05791716, 4209850.57679172, 
4206768.02920257, 4202640.72257962, 4201724.19664976, 4202048.71970684, 
4210266.71218086, 4211609.76577034, 4212919.86773861, 4214384.5525767, 
4217211.37538879, 4218756.84466467, 4221166.17811783, 4228017.58153775, 
4230026.26265049, 4232028.60673767, 4232789.05489458, 4233871.09393742, 
4235979.46541856, 4236654.30348682, 4236705.67853229, 4237981.59548233, 
4239476.95011435), dim = c(23L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg")), structure(c(-2514215.55544332, -2514108.60295901, -2516474.73663247, 
-2518453.22967354, -2518908.49380877, -2517737.73005421, -2514790.73574887, 
-2515401.76286617, -2516656.81238836, -2517508.2364059, -2518533.2392692, 
-2518414.60386001, -2519493.57285708, -2521308.60450706, -2522859.54465132, 
-2522782.19438828, -2519230.80640189, -2519067.17337389, -2517564.67479945, 
-2516916.9539517, -2512102.05979041, -2510829.87788662, -2511752.66501718, 
-2514557.60667386, -2515920.84566496, -2514983.12625848, -2514066.12140984, 
-2512428.26286561, -2511040.1031902, -2507615.61588024, -2504527.64229299, 
-2497948.21335612, -2490438.90679884, -2489073.30059575, -2487101.60591081, 
-2485048.02119662, -2479179.66167563, -2478234.89283411, -2475638.73235202, 
-2472077.42625223, -2470917.73700336, -2467210.7719459, -2465146.80587687, 
-2464756.69068305, 3979240.91750093, 3979869.21125782, 3982644.50267001, 
3985854.68251267, 3987334.77896143, 3993083.57016668, 3993893.46660858, 
3996642.38103645, 3997717.92190821, 3998764.63617605, 4001094.53234293, 
4001710.30999891, 4005466.48050885, 4007408.00327857, 4008685.16070701, 
4010733.93808285, 4013893.53011966, 4015883.42334632, 4019040.48911394, 
4019761.24850631, 4021136.44266445, 4026524.4311791, 4028994.82021167, 
4031357.65934572, 4037345.31065658, 4040407.62428636, 4040939.29886049, 
4040742.91253541, 4040268.24547748, 4042092.34070452, 4043007.46779132, 
4041772.22555455, 4041533.19291715, 4041059.24079698, 4039730.02831388, 
4039490.95098141, 4039436.6081968, 4039944.23676835, 4039802.80034074, 
4036721.32471232, 4035018.40468451, 4031619.42696723, 4031376.16720174, 
4032661.24307734), dim = c(44L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg")), structure(c(-2455802.34972538, -2453391.28517002, -2451117.68782068, 
-2450222.14719026, -2451215.76855211, -2449752.46680174, -2444621.43262733, 
-2440904.34564473, -2437502.4275941, -2434979.22741248, -2434870.06439399, 
-2434314.70965303, -2429762.91818513, -2425666.797462, -2423226.98639026, 
-2417776.68884648, -2417968.12255325, -2417331.4894273, -2413444.50430002, 
-2411233.41758996, -2410265.12703715, -2409295.50378024, -2408307.88367522, 
-2407051.25040841, -2403963.12093879, -2399321.78235239, -2397528.97342155, 
-2396716.10233376, -2396620.75446153, -2397682.10864439, 3944200.72880045, 
3945490.44731529, 3947949.34275907, 3950434.19115405, 3951676.29139213, 
3954037.43418137, 3956904.81201506, 3957923.75787283, 3958278.09229342, 
3958897.96171749, 3960183.01602756, 3961283.87424064, 3963988.73352533, 
3964811.08035148, 3965072.69119469, 3968963.83065237, 3970066.35833318, 
3970931.15683084, 3973704.79428498, 3974769.45399505, 3975965.88168327, 
3978409.45939458, 3979858.37552362, 3980875.28452987, 3981978.04354102, 
3987999.98150925, 3989616.56833822, 3991162.64095591, 3991858.59803784, 
3993651.94569022), dim = c(30L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg")), structure(c(-2415373.75111227, -2414648.14835331, -2412390.74585963, 
-2410056.6386044, -2405120.36599989, -2402861.10810753, -2402986.24635509, 
-2406418.46686885, -2406982.27650905, -2405007.7006716, -2402118.76144927, 
-2398386.07718651, -2396958.87590622, -2394897.1222264, -2393341.57970908, 
-2389037.11456408, -2388414.48535736, -2384350.37346166, -2383080.34788004, 
-2381034.58159959, -2379091.73450143, -2377843.05765348, -2377693.25288159, 
-2376955.21571413, -2370738.31788899, -2368157.17696267, -2366350.53207778, 
-2365504.09842216, -2364203.71185746, -2361941.81933682, -2362724.85045673, 
-2362640.35403509, -2360130.16923897, -2356745.08525755, 3917793.08252573, 
3918212.12755188, 3918467.4571113, 3919265.73758435, 3925540.65361894, 
3929226.40695579, 3934178.55867348, 3940737.70011046, 3943334.05038866, 
3946991.37945152, 3948513.08487937, 3952165.26827236, 3952282.46236242, 
3952013.12261047, 3952634.66620483, 3956910.69385851, 3958186.40719334, 
3957769.94115641, 3957220.33234559, 3956915.42765594, 3957922.21259561, 
3959127.65713169, 3960775.84966022, 3963760.03373303, 3966038.71645059, 
3967760.91808983, 3969463.43424552, 3969571.34062276, 3969492.27068219, 
3970560.1252503, 3972321.63833911, 3974664.33394043, 3975945.15814048, 
3975988.18740328), dim = c(34L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
"sfg"))), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -2990072.09038422, 
ymin = 3917793.08252573, xmax = -2356745.08525755, ymax = 4301496.30889971
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "ESRI:102003", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]],\n    CONVERSION[\"USA_Contiguous_Albers_Equal_Area_Conic\",\n        METHOD[\"Albers Equal Area\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",37.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",-96,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",29.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",45.5,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"unknown\"],\n        AREA[\"USA - CONUS - onshore\"],\n        BBOX[24.41,-124.79,49.38,-66.91]],\n    ID[\"ESRI\",102003]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(NAMEEN = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you include your data?

Comment: Which package gives you the `plot_usmap` function?

Comment: @Spacedman the usmap package.

Comment: @Russ I've added some sample data to the question, I can't guarantee that the sample of the rivers data set includes any rivers in AK or HI, though.

Comment: Found that package eventually, and it seems to use data for AK and HI that is already transformed to be in its modified places, and no clues as to how these have been transformed, so I think you'll have to use another technique for mapping all the states this way.

Comment: The `tigris` package has a function `shift_geometry` which takes a geographically correct US map data set and shift AK and HI (and Puerto Rico if present). I think it can be used to shift any data if you construct it carefully enough...

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks! I tried `shift_geometry` (mentioned in post). It didn't work, but I suspect it's because there are rivers in US territories (e.g. USVI, Guam, etc.) and `shift_geometry` says it won't work if there is data outside CONUS+AK+HI+PR, and I'm sure there is a way to restrict the rivers data set but since I don't know what the offending data is I don't know how to remove it...

Comment: Are you saying this could work with your sample data but your larger data set has USVI, Guam etc and so fails? If you filter them out (eg by intersection with some boundary polygons) then it will all work for you?

Comment: @Spacedman I think so. This is based on the docs for `shift_geometry` which say: "The function is also designed to work exclusively with features in the continental United States, Alaska, Hawaii, and Puerto Rico. If your dataset includes features outside these areas (e.g. other US territories or other countries), you may get unworkable results. It is advisable to filter out those features before using shift_geometry()." I'm hoping to try this today.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've managed to answer my own question! Here's what I had to do. For some reason, if I use `shift_geometry` within `geom_sf`, it works--but if I do it to the data frame before plotting...it doesn't.

```
#Get a state map from tigris (=Census)
state_geo <- tigris::states(class = "sf", cb=TRUE, progress_bar=FALSE, resolution="20m")

#Marry some variables to each state
state_geo <- left_join(state_geo, state_difference,by=c("STUSPS"="state"))

#Get the rivers data
rivers <- st_read("sources/NA_Lakes_and_Rivers/data")

#We only need rivers (TYPE 17) in the US.
rivers2 <- rivers %>% filter(COUNTRY=="USA", TYPE=="17") %>% dplyr::select(c("geometry","NAMEEN"))

#Need to match the projections
state_geo <- sf::st_transform(state_geo,"ESRI:102003")
rivers2 <- sf::st_transform(rivers2,"ESRI:102003")

#This works!
ggplot()+geom_sf(data=shift_geometry(state_geo),aes(fill=median_premium))+
  geom_sf(data=shift_geometry(rivers2))+coord_sf(datum = NA)
```